# Converting a hexadecimal digest to base64 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, base64, md5, digest

I have a string representation of a MD5 hex digest for a file, that I want to convert to base64 in order to use the Content-MD5 HTTP header when uploading it. Is there a clearer or more efficient mechanism to do than the following?

```
def hex_to_base64_digest(hexdigest)
  [[hexdigest].pack("H*")].pack("m").strip
end

hex_digest = "65a8e27d8879283831b664bd8b7f0ad4"
expected_base64_digest = "ZajifYh5KDgxtmS9i38K1A=="

raise "Does not match" unless hex_to_base64_digest(hex_digest) === expected_base64_digest
```

Comment: Looks pretty clear and efficient to me.  The only thing that might be faster/clearer is a native hook that does exactly the "hex_to_base64_digest" method.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Seems pretty clear and efficient to me. You can save the call to strip by specifying 0 count for the 'm' pack format [(if count is 0, no line feed are added, see RFC 4648)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack)

```
def hex_to_base64_digest(hexdigest)
  [[hexdigest].pack("H*")].pack("m0")
end
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like that may be the case. Just seems that wrapping each parameter in array is untidy.

Comment: If anyone looking from Base64 to Hex below is the method i used.
```
    *def base64_to_hex(base64_string)
      base64_string.scan(/.{4}/).map do |b| 
        b.unpack('m0').first.unpack('H*')
      end.join
    end*
```