# Active Storage Checksum confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checksum, rails-activestorage

I just uploaded a test file (png image) using Active Storage to Amazon S3.

One think i've noticed is that the `etag` returned for the file from the S3 API is different from the `checksum` stored in the blob record in the database for that file.

I ran an MD5 checksum on this site: https://appdevtools.com/checksum-calculator for the file and it matches the S3 `etag`.

Why is the `checksum` stored in the DB blob different?

test-file.png:

```
Amazon S3 eTag via API:                  f1d0a62d6890cf4c4ecb4337c6d789df
`checksum` in Database:                  8dCmLWiQz0xOy0M3xteJ3w==
MD5 Checksum when checking on website:   f1d0a62d6890cf4c4ecb4337c6d789df
```

Can anyone explain this and also how the one in the database relates to the file?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657619/how-is-the-checksum-calculated-in-the-blobs-table-for-rails-activestorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same value, stored differently.

The value `"f1d0a62d6890cf4c4ecb4337c6d789df"` is a hex string.

The value `"8dCmLWiQz0xOy0M3xteJ3w=="` is a base64-encoded string.

Both represent the same raw bytes of the checksum.

To convert from base64 to hex:

```rb
Base64.decode64('8dCmLWiQz0xOy0M3xteJ3w==').unpack('H*')
 => ["f1d0a62d6890cf4c4ecb4337c6d789df"]
```

To convert from hex to base64:

```rb
Base64.encode64(["f1d0a62d6890cf4c4ecb4337c6d789df"].pack('H*')).chomp
 => "8dCmLWiQz0xOy0M3xteJ3w=="
```