# Calculate base64digest by md5 digest string

Tags: ruby, hash, md5

I have a string, that can be received by calling

```
md5 = Digest::MD5.new
md5.update 'abc'
str = md5.to_s
# str == '900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72'
```

I actually don't do so, I only receive this string as an input.

Now I want to receive a result similar to calling

```
md5.base64digest
# kAFQmDzST7DWlj99KOF/cg==
```

Summing up: I want to get base64digest of md5 having only `digest.to_s` as in input.
Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you're asking, but you may want to know how to convert a hex encoded string to a base64 encoded string. If so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987466/9014097).

Comment: @Topaco Wow, that's exactly it! You got it right, thank you!